# Error in UseMethod(“cld”) : no applicable method for 'cld' applied to an object of class "emmGrid"

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, boxplot

I am trying to run a R code with Jupyter Notebook for visualzing a boxplot, but I am getting this error:

```
Error in UseMethod(“cld”) : no applicable method for 'cld' applied to an object of class "emmGrid"
```

The code in R:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lme4)
library(emmeans)
library(multcomp)



# set vector with colors and label
COL <- c("Fallow" = "slategray", "Mustard" = "red3" , "Mix4" = "orchid3", "Mix12"= "orange4")
SHP <- c("Fallow"=21,"Mustard"=22,"Mix4"=23, "Mix12"=24)


# generate data frame with original data
data <- data.frame(cc_variant = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("Fallow", "Mustard", "Mix4", "Mix12"), class = "factor"),
                   Date = structure(c(17092, 17093, 17098, 17092, 17092, 17092, 17093, 17093, 17093, 17098, 17098, 17098), class = "Date"),
                   NEE = c(52.3186092, 36.752742, 34.590816, -516.868370737168, -617.110003978854, -182.24567563611, -102.63776100067, -431.558870280712, -139.041211720174, -114.099387563412, -400.212603947375, -175.332083704246)
)


lm_NEE <- lmer(NEE ~ cc_variant + (1|Date), data=data)
df_NEE <- cld(emmeans(lm_NEE, specs ="cc_variant"), Letters=letters, sort=FALSE)

# Plot for BFS
ggplot(data, aes(x= cc_variant, y=NEE, fill= cc_variant))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  scale_fill_manual(values = COL, guide=FALSE)+
  geom_text(data= df_NEE ,aes(y=-600,x=cc_variant, label=.group))+
  labs(x="Catch crop variant",  y=expression("NEE (mg CO"[2]~"- C"~m^{-2}~h^{-1}~")"), fill="")+
  theme_myBW

ggsave("Fig1.png", width = 84, height = 70, units = "mm", dpi = 600)
```

Altough this code works perfectly when I try to run it using R Studio.

Comment: it has nothing to do with jupyter most likely. works for me on jupyter. i guess you are using different versions of R and packages in jupyter notebook and Rstudio. can you try to use the same R version

Comment: @StupidWolf thanks a lot for trying to help me, can you please more explain? how to verify the same R version used in jupyter ?

Comment: sessionInfo() will give you the version... i needa check how to how to find the path of R installation

Comment: R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Comment: thats was in R studio and in Jupyter?

Comment: it will be the same command

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224383/discussion-between-anouar-and-stupidwolf).

Comment: My suggestion is to give up. cld() is a lousy and misleading way to summarize pairwise tests.

Comment: @RussLenth Thanks for your answer, it is resolved, it was a confuse between the r version